# for loop, new column, length > 1, in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I did a little searching and couldn't find anything exactly like my issue. I've done almost the exact same loop many times before, except it's usually more like "Make X (a factor) whenever you have Y (some other factor)".

Here's my code:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(age_cont)){
      if(age_cont$Choice[i] == 1){
        age_cont$Rank[i] = "Never"
      }
      else if(age_cont$Choice[i] == 2){
        age_cont$Rank[i] = "Sometimes"
      }
      else if(age_cont[i] == 3){
        age_cont$Rank[i] = "Frequently"
      }
      else {
        age_cont$Rank[i] = "Always"
      }
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(age_cont, i) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (age_cont[i] == 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (age_cont[i] == 4) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (age_cont[i] == 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (age_cont[i] == 4) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
```

The Choice variable is ordinal (1-4), and I'm trying to create a new column that's parallel to that, but with names instead of numbers. I've tried changing the Choice variable to a factor and rerunning the loop, and even tried simply to  rename each number to a name (within the same column) also, but that didn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is an error in the line

```
   else if(age_cont[i] == 3){
```

I think you meant

```
   else if(age_cont$Choice[i] == 3){
```

This should explain the error message.

Comment: Yes, but still not getting my Rank column. Just "always" for every one.

Comment: By the way, before the `else if` there has to be a closing `}` in the same line, as in `} if else (cond) {`. Other than that, I can not see anything wrong from what I can see in your question.

Comment: I think my answer fixed the error you have mentioned, and solved the question you've asked. If you have a different problem now, post it as a different question with the error messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer that allows you to drop the for loop and the several `if`s by doing a join with a table that gives you the rank. I do a left join and then fill the na's so as to mimic the else clause.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(Choice = sample(1:4, 10, replace = TRUE))

transco <- tribble( ~Choice, ~Rank,
1, "Never",
2, "Sometimes",
3, "Frequently")

df %>% left_join(transco, by = "Choice") %>%
    replace_na(list(Rank = "Always"))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Choice       Rank
    <dbl>      <chr>
1       2  Sometimes
2       2  Sometimes
3       3 Frequently
4       4     Always
5       1      Never
6       4     Always
7       4     Always
8       3 Frequently
9       3 Frequently
10      1      Never
```

Answer (score 0):

use everywhere

```
age_cont$Choice[i] %in% #your_number
```

instead of

```
age_cont$Choice[i] == #your_number
```

Also, change `age_cont[i] == 3` to `age_cont$Count[i] %in% 3`

This should solve your problem.